# Oracle Service Cloud File Attachment upload/view

Tags: php, rightnow-crm

Im new to service cloud and have been tasked with figuring out a way to save file attachments to custom objects. I believe what I have thus far accomplishes just that as I can see the new records being created in my object. My next step is to figure out a way to find uploaded files given an ID and display a clickable link that will open in a new tab to display the uploaded file's contents. (similar to the stock FileListDisplay widget). According to the Connect PHP API documentation, no ROQL query or fetch() returns any file attachment data. How would I go about displaying uploaded files?

Code so far (shortened for brevity)

View:

```
   <form action="https://test.rightnowdemo.com/app/Upload2/uploadcontroller2" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" />
      <div>
     <h3>Select a .txt file only:</h3><br />
       <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="2000000" />
       <label for="userfile">Select a file:</label>
       <input type="file" class="form-control" name="userfile" /><br>
       <input type="submit" class="nybeButton" value="Send" />
     </div>
  </form>
```

controller:

```
function store_attachment($FileName, $FileLocation, $FileType)
{


    $MyDocument = new RightNow\Connect\v1_1\UPLOAD\Documents();
    $MyDocument->FileAttachments = new RightNow\Connect\v1_1\FileAttachmentArray();
    $MyDocument->UserName = "Test user";
    $fattach = new RightNow\Connect\v1_1\FileAttachment();

    $fattach->ContentType = $FileType;

    $file = $FileLocation;
    $fattach->setFile($file);
    $fattach->FileName = $FileName;
    $MyDocument->FileAttachments[] = $fattach;
    //\RightNow\Libraries\AbuseDetection::check();
    $MyDocument->save();
}
$FileName = $_FILES["userfile"]["name"];
$FileLocation = get_cfg_var('upload_tmp_dir') . "/" . $_FILES["userfile"]["name"];
$FileType = $_FILES["userfile"]["type"];
store_attachment($FileName, $FileLocation, $FileType);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A similar question [was asked on the OSvC communities](http://communities.rightnow.com/posts/1be39f576d) lately.  Generally, there's no way to *get* the file data through Connect for PHP; you can only set through Connect (we used to have some scripts to get around this with PHP, but I believe that Prod Dev has closed all PHP methods to access the file servers).  You must use the SOAP API to retrieve the files through your code.

However, if you just want to display a link on Customer Portal to the file, then you can follow the following format, as per Arun's answer in the communities:

```
<a href="/ci/fattach/get/<?php echo $file->ID; ?>/<?php echo $file->CreatedTime; ?>/filename/<?php echo urlencode($file->FileName); ?>">Download File</a>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. How is the $file variable being set? My first assumption was to set it equal to the result of a  ROQL query (for example- select FileAttachments from <package>.<customobject> where id =... ) But after reading the documentation, I saw that ROQL doesn't return any file attachment data.

Comment: You can use ROQL to query for file attachments for a given object.  Here's an example for getting the data from an incident: 'SELECT I.FileAttachments.* FROM Incident I WHERE I.FileAttachments.ID IS NOT NULL LIMIT 1'

Comment: Great Thank you. My query returns an array which is fine because I'm still able to build the URL using the array elements. My problem is now, when we click the "Download File" link, it says I don't have permission to view the document. I'm signed into the same account I was when the file was uploaded.

Comment: The result of the file attachment query will always be an array of one or more elements since it's a one to many relationship between the object and file attachments.  Is the "Private" flag set to false when you add the file to your array?  If it's set to true, it will not be exposed.

Comment: Is this something I have to do in my custom controller like `$fattach->Private = "false"`?

Comment: Yes, it should be like that.  You can set current file attachments using the Agent Console too.  Take a look at the FileAttachment object in the Connect Common Object Model for the parameters that you can set.

Comment: I've tried using `$fattach->Private = false` as well as setting it to `0` as I noticed that the field is an integer data type to no avail. I'm still being denied access to view/download the file.

Comment: Does the file attachment show as public when you view the record in the agent console?

Comment: in Object Explorer? I'm sorry I'm still really new to this!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92318/discussion-between-scott-harwell-and-exeleon).

Comment: Replied back in chat @Scott Harwell